# Modifying this URL validation regex to accept whats after the .com part

Tags: php, regex

Over the years, I used this regex to validate urls, and it's done an 'ok' job. The problem is, it  won't validate after the `.com` part. It'll only validate `http://www.domain.com`. Anything more, and it'll throw an error.

```
function theUrl($rUrl)
    {
        if (preg_match('/^((http|https):\/{2})([w]{3})([\.]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\.]{1})((a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|aero|arpa)|(b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|biz)|(c[acdfghiklmnorsuvxyz]|cat|co.in|com|coop)|d[ejkmoz]|(e[ceghrstu]|edu)|f[ijkmor]|(g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|gov)|h[kmnrtu]|(i[delmnoqrst]|info|int)|(j[emop]|jobs)|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|(m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|mil|mobi|museum)|(n[acefgilopruz]|name|net)|(om|org)|(p[aefghklmnrstwy]|pro)|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortvyz]|(t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|travel)|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])$/i', $rUrl))
        {
            return true;
        }       
    }
```

Can you help me with how the part after the `.com` should be for best results?

Comment: What's the engine? JavaScript? PHP?

Comment: `cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz` can be written as `c-gil-oq-uwxyz` within `[]`

Comment: This thing is used in php

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ What does that mean?

Comment: @Norman you dont need to specify each character within a range..so instead of writing each alphabet you can specify the range instead like `a-z` which covers all the characters within `a` and `z`..this would work only within `[]`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Ah! Ok! Got it.

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to use one of the native PHP functions instead of a custom regular expression, such as:

- [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
- [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) using the `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` type.